# rsyslog regex wont become greedy

Tags: regex, templates, rsyslog

I am writing a rsyslog-template to filter src and dst ip from events, but the regexpression is only returning the first match.

**Sample Event:**

ulogd[20230]: id="2002" severity="info" sys="SecureNet" sub="packetfilter" name="Packet accepted" action="accept" fwrule="89" initf="eth1" outitf="eth0" srcmac="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:2c" dstmac="00:11:22:ff:cc:aa" srcip="10.10.1.250" dstip="192.168.0.1" proto="6" length="52" tos="0x00" prec="0x00" ttl="127" srcport="64405" dstport="1133" tcpflags="ACK"

**Template_syntax**

```
%msg:R,ERE,0,FIELD:([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})+--end%
```

**REGEX**

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})+
```

I am testing with:
https://www.rsyslog.com/regex/

Comment: Give us more and better REAL sample data. And give us the purified regex. it looks not like a regex. I receive **NO MATCH** with your sample data and your regex.

Comment: can you share one sample log ?

Comment: also greeediness is something else. You dont need a `+` at the end. Well, everithing works fine [here](https://regex101.com/r/4jXBEJ/1)

Comment: cant use /g - thought I could cover the multiple matches with (regex)+

Comment: no (regex)+ just means that your regex pattern mathes ones and could match more time right behind the previos.   

(abc)+ will match "abc", "abcabc" but not "abcdefabc" or "abc def abc"
+

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Do you have an idea, how I can just match both IPs without \g ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have to match exactly 2 ips, then you can just repeat the regex pattern in 2 property replacers, where the second one specifies that the second matching ip address is to be taken.

Using "..." to stand for the pattern `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}`, just to make it more readable, you would have

```
%msg:R,ERE,0,FIELD,0:...--end%
%msg:R,ERE,0,FIELD,1:...--end%
```

or in full:

```
$template outfmt,"%msg:R,ERE,0,FIELD,0:[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}--end%  %msg:R,ERE,0,FIELD,1:[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}--end%\n"
```

Comment: too bad there is no match,global or something like that and you gotta repeat to get what u want - but it works out fine, thank you very much.